# How to Scroll in Date Picker in Calendar using Appium Java?

Tags: java, scroll, appium, appium-android

I wanted to select Past/Future years in the Android Application. I tried with the below functionality. But it's not working. Can anyone help me?

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new     
UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new     
UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I will explain in Python, you can use the equivalent for Java**

**Here is the procedure:**

1. Get the focused element attribute to find what is selected now. You can check the Year on the top or year picker center (green) element. I've pointed in the picture below.

[image: Focused Element]

```
current_focus_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath({#})  #xpath of the focused year or selected year text on the header

focused_year_value = current_focus_element.get_attribute('value') # assume it is 2021
```

2. Swipe up or down (year by year) from Origin (current focused year) to Destination (the year above or below current year): If the target is for the past (like 2020), we should swipe down. Up for the future. (We can calculate `target year - current focused element`. if the result is `positive`, we should swipe down. Up for `negative` as well )

```
# assuming the target is 2019

difference = focused_year_value-target  # 2021-2019 = 2 (positive)

# as it is positive we should swipe down. So we should find the coordinates of '2021' and '2022' and swipe from 2021 to 2022 for going down.

origin_coordinates = driver.find_by_xpath(FOCUSED_YEAR_XPATH).location  #2021

destination_coordinates = driver.find_by_xpath(BELOW_YEAR_XPATH).location  #2022

driver.swipe(start_x=int(origin_coordinates['x']), start_y=int(origin_coordinates['y']),
end_x=int(destination_coordinates['x']),end_y=int(destination_coordinates['y'])
```

3. Check the focused element. If we reach to the target, stop swiping, otherwise continue.

```
focused_year_value = current_focus_element.get_attribute('value')

if focusd_year_value == 2019:
    return

else:
   # [Step 2]
```

If this Helps, hit the green tick. :)

Comment: @Mohammand Monfared: I think in Appium, swipe function is deprecated. So needs to check for alternative solution.

Comment: @Madhukar No, it hasn't. 

https://i.imgur.com/QEVKDam.png